# How can I increase stroke of a text or make the text bold in an Image? in Python

Tags: image, image-processing

Suppose I have the following image:

[Demo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTqZW.jpg)

Now I want to increase the stroke of the texts in the image or make the font in the image bold.
Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can use erosion on the text image, using a small structuring element. If the effect is too pronounced, you can process in three steps: enlarge the image, erode, shrink to the initial scale.

Answer (score 0):

Original:

[image]

Below, the results of straight 3x3 erosion, then doubling, erosion and halving:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: @SaqueebAbdullah: made with proprietary software. This will be three lines of OpenCV.